# Use of mexSet to access CData via a MEX file

Tags: matlab, mex, cdata

I'm trying to plot data out from a MEX file (C language). To do this fast, I would like to use what corresponds to the following Matlab code:

```
figure; imagehandle = imagesc(rand(500));
new_CData = rand(500);
set(newCData,imagehandle);
```

For this, the command mexSet() should be working. Ideally, I want something like this

```
mex plotX.c
figure; imagehandle = imagesc(rand(500)); 
A = rand(500);
plotX(A,imagehandle)
```

with a mex-Function plotX. Here is my tryout:

```
#include "mex.h"
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    double *x, imagehandle;

    (void) plhs;
    x = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);

    imagehandle = mxGetScalar(prhs[1]);
    mexSet(imagehandle,"Cdata",x);
}
```

This can be compiled, but I get the following error: "Error using plotX. Numeric or logical matrix required for image CData".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: P.S. the reason I want to plot in MEX is that I have the data as lib.pointers, and I don't want to convert them into a Matlab matrix before plotting, but plotting them directly from their physical location.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
#include "mex.h"
 void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
 {
    double *x, imagehandle;
    (void) plhs;
    imagehandle = mxGetScalar(prhs[1]);
    mexSet(imagehandle,"Cdata",prhs[0]);
 }
```

I found this out when I used a different compiler which gave me the following error: " note: expected ‘struct mxArray *’ but argument is of type ‘double *’". And prhs[] is already a mxArray, so easy to solve ...